# Select rows where field is maximum, relative to another field

Tags: sql, max

I have data in the following format:

**ID - Value**
a - 1
a - 2
a - 3
a - 4
b - 1
b - 2
b - 3
c - 1
c - 2
d - 4

And I would like to select rows with the maximum value for each ID, so that the output would be:

ID  Value
a - 4
b - 3
c - 2
d - 4

I have tried conditioning on max(value), but am having trouble making this relative to the ID

Comment: `SELECT id, max(value)`  .. `GROUP BY id` or `SELECT id, max(value) .. GROUP BY id HAVING max(value)` ...   ? if atleast I didn't miss something obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood that correctly, what you are trying to do is get the Max value per ID. If that is your intention, the query below should work fine:

```
select max(value) from myTable group by ID;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: add id in select column so output contain id-max value

Comment: Yes this works (with the ID in the select statement) - I think I was just confusing myself earlier & this is pretty straightforward query.  Thanks !